# Difference between - var+1 and var++

Tags: javascript, node.js, int

im wondering, why int++ is not working, but int+1 is working. Someone have an idea why this happend in my example? Is there any difference?

```
function retryFunction(something, count) {
     if (!count) {
         count = 0;
     }

     console.log(typeof count);
     console.log(count);

     if (count < 5) {
          return setTimeout(function () {
              //working
              retryFunction(something, count+1);

              //not working
              retryFunction(something, count++);
          }, 1000)
      }
}

retryFunction(null);
```

Comment: (whatever "not working" means) because in the second case `count` is incemented *after* the call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "++" and "+= 1 " operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988140/what-is-the-difference-between-and-1-operators)

Comment: ↑ It's not the same language, but applies.

Comment: Try ++count instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the shorthand arithmetic operator ++ after the variable name return 2 in the following statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218299/why-doesnt-the-shorthand-arithmetic-operator-after-the-variable-name-return)

Answer (score 5):

The expression `count + 1` adds `1` to `count` and "returns" the result of that.

The expression `count++` returns the current value of `count`, and *then* adds `1` to `count` (thereby modifying the variable value, but after the old value was used).

Comment: `count + 1` also can be written as `++count`

Comment: @semanser Except it doesn't do the same thing. `count + 1` doesn't modify `count`, while `++count` does.

Comment: You may add this your answer. Here is also a little example on  [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f@/LLFIITm/NK9EwVbBwJorOT@vOD8nVS8nP11DWxssoYkqilNMW5tolYbYVf7/DwA "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") which demonstrate this.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Generally yes, but not in the case of OP.

Answer (score 2):

Prefix increment vs. postfix increment operator. Speaking loosely in the context of your example, `count++` says "call the function with the original value, then increment and store in the variable". If you were however to use `++count`, this says "increment the variable and send the result to the function."

NB. Whilst `++count` would "work", what you actually want is count + 1; it makes no sense to store the result in the passed parameter in this context.